# Is there a word/phrase for an organisation whose stated aims would put itself out of business?

Tags: idioms, adjectives

There are many bodies that claim to have worthy aims, but if they achieved them they would put themselves out of business, so they avoid doing anything effective, or even do more harm than good. Common themes are the environment, health and various forms of equality.

Is there a word or simple phrase that describes such an organisation?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I think that 'self-destructive' might fit.

Comment: [*Quango*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quango) [BrE] comes to mind, although its meaning is rather specific. Anyway, such organizations tend to be government departments.

Comment: @Mick that takes the cynical view that all Quangos exist only to perpetuate themselves, rather than solve the problem they were created to solve.   Perhaps some of them do but I don't think it's the norm.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yeah! But if they actually solved the problems that they were intended to address, what then? Of course, some quangos are intended to address ongoing problems, but many of them seem to be a waste of time (at least in the UK).

Comment: hey @Mick - you're comment is all of correct, astute, an sadly not funny :/

Comment: [*Ad hoc*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ad-hoc) is the best that I can think of, e.g. an *ad hoc* committee.

Comment: @Mick Quangos, like many things, tend to only make the news when they do something bad.  There are more Quangos in the UK than you might think, and most of the "Quango Cash" goes on things which you might prefer to carry on existing, like the NHS https://www.express.co.uk/life-style/health/436350/Meet-the-biggest-quango-in-the-world-NHS-England

Comment: Also, even if some Quangos do fit the requirements of the question, the word "Quango" isn't itself synonymous with the requirements.

Comment: You mean like companies that have planned obsolescence as a centerpiece of their business plan, because if they actually made the best widget they could their customers would only ever buy the one?

Comment: @1006a OP seems to also/primarily asking about a mission statement of "Save the Environment" or "Equal Pay for Women". Does the organization disband after it achieves its goals? (Assuming it's a goal that can be achieved – you can't save the environment for all time.) I suppose this would also apply to "Cure for Cancer" or a business based on the small pox vaccine (which is "eradicated", but apparently still a vaccine that some people get).

Comment: @Max Williams Unfortunately more money going into the NHS isn't nceessarily a good thing, because a lot of it doesn't ultimately get spent on patients' well-being. It's notorious for "non-jobs", and things like very expensive IT projects that fail to produce a system fit for purpose. And why is it spending money on TV adverts encouraging people to use services that are already overloaded?

Comment: @realh this isn't the forum for that discussion.  Hopefully we can agree that the NHS doesn't deliberately avoid doing anything effective lest it succeed and  "go out of business", which is what this question is asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a generic term for the type of organisation, but the behaviour you describe is **self-defeating** or, if it's very obviously shooting itself in the feet, **self-sabotaging**.

Comment: Yes, those seem to be about the closest we can get in a word or two unless a new word is invented.

Answer (score 2):

There may be no catch-all term. If you are talking about a committee, then [*ad hoc*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ad-hoc) would be entirely appropriate:

> **ad hoc** adjective [ before noun ]
>   ​
>   made or happening only for a particular purpose or need, not planned before it happens:
>
> - an ad hoc committee/meeting

Cambridge Dictionary